# Unable to set the GroupStyle for a ListBox via Style?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to create a Style that will set the GroupStyle property for my ListBox controls however I am getting a compile time error:

```
The Property Setter 'GroupStyle' cannot be set because it does not have an accessible set accessor.
```

My Style setter looks like this:

```
        <Setter Property="ListBox.GroupStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Is there a work-around for this, and also, if there is no setter for this property, then how are we able to use property-setter syntax for it in XAML to define it inline, in the first place? (still new to WPF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out the answer - it's because of the way the XAML compiler treats any content between the element tags, based on the type of the property mapped to the content I just remembered!

If the property is a ContentControl, then the element you define between two tags gets assigned to that Content property, however, if the element is an instance of an IList (which is what GroupStyle is), then .NET actually calls .Add() underneath the covers

In this case, the GroupStyle is actually an ObservableCollection and hence an IList, therefore we are not actually assigning to the GroupStyle object, we are ADDING to the collection.

In otherwords, the type of the property that is represented by content (mapped via the ContentProperty attribute of a control) in between the element tags influences the way the XAML compiler interprets it (direct assignment or calling .Add())

Comment: Any code example of the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can the follwing:

```
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource listContainerStyle}"/>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

And than

```
<Style x:Key="listContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="True">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Avi.

Answer (score 1):

```
//set you datatemplate as a resource
<DataTemplate x:Key="categoryTemplate">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>


//set header template binding to staticresource
<ListBox Name="lst"> 
   <ListBox.GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource categoryTemplate}" />
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This works thanks! From the perspective of XAML however, why is it we can define a GroupStyle inline with a blank <GroupStyle /> using property-setter syntax when the property has no setter though? I'm confused about that.

Comment: I will mark your answer as the solution if you can answer the last question too :)

Comment: it is because GroupStyle doesn't have a setter public ObservableCollection<GroupStyle> GroupStyle { get; } (msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that (I even mentioned it has no property setter) - so why does the property-setter syntax of XAML work?

Comment: Because the setter works on HeaderTemplate which have a setter unlike GroupStyle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupstyle.headertemplate(v=vs.90).aspx ;-)

Comment: But I'm able to do <ListBox.GroupStyle> <GroupStyle /> </ListBox.GroupStyle> ..isn't this technically creating a new GroupStyle object and setting it?

Comment: yes, but you set value only through properties GroupStyle (containstyle,headertemplate...) when you specify GroupStyle item, it is only a get access not a set in <ListBox.GroupStyle> <GroupStyle /> </ListBox.GroupStyle>

Comment: Ahh thank you, that explains my confusion - I'm still new to WPF :)

Comment: Actually I just tested it then - doing <ListBox.GroupStyle> <GroupStyle /> </ListBox.GroupStyle> DOES create a new GroupStyle object ...at runtime I tested the debugger and the Count = 0, but if I put <Group Style /> the Count = 1 ..so it actually does create it

Answer (score 0):

in order to understand well
you can add groupstyle in code (it is what XAML do)

```
GroupStyle g = new GroupStyle();
ListBox ls = new ListBox();
ls.GroupStyle.Add(g);
```

but you can't set GroupStyle

```
GroupStyle g = new GroupStyle();
ListBox ls = new ListBox();
ls.GroupStyle=g;//error because GroupStyle has only a getter
```

Comment: The confusion is because ListBox.GroupStyle propertie is a container of GroupStyle