# Issue creating style to be set as the GroupStyle of some ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I'm trying to implement the [following code](http://www.jarloo.com/wpf-combobox-with-groupings/), with the difference that I would like this to apply to a style so that I can set it for any `ComboBox` that I like (i.e. I am creating a number of ComboBoxes dynamically from the code behind due to specific unchangeable requirements, and would like to add `GroupStyles` to each of them).

I am relatively new to `WPF` and `XAML`, so I thought of doing so through a `Style` and specifying the `GroupStyles` in the `ControlTemplate`, and then just applying the style to the respective `ComboBoxes`. This is what I've tried so far, but the code will not compile (mainly due to the `<ComboBox.GroupStyle>` part).

```
<Style x:Name="valuesComboStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle>
                                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle>
                            </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `DataTemple` somewhere in the resources. And use it for every `Combobox` you  need.

Here is the code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="groupStyle">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"  x:Key="comboBoxItemStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Label Background="Red" Content="{Binding Item}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ComboBox Height="27" Width="195" DisplayMemberPath="Item" Name="cboGroup"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource comboBoxItemStyle}">
        <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource groupStyle}"/>
        </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT:** I create a new combobox and set some items and set the style you are looking for. (I update the code in you link)

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;


        ComboBox comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
        comboBox1.Height = 23;
        comboBox1.Width = 200;

        GroupStyle style = new GroupStyle();
        style.HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("groupStyle");
        comboBox1.GroupStyle.Add(style);
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Item";
        ObservableCollection<CategoryItem<string>> items = new ObservableCollection<CategoryItem<string>>();

        items.Add(new CategoryItem<string> { Category = "Warm Colors", Item = "Orange" });
        items.Add(new CategoryItem<string> { Category = "Warm Colors", Item = "Red" });
        items.Add(new CategoryItem<string> { Category = "Warm Colors", Item = "Pink" });
        items.Add(new CategoryItem<string> { Category = "Cool Colors", Item = "Blue" });
        items.Add(new CategoryItem<string> { Category = "Cool Colors", Item = "Purple" });
        items.Add(new CategoryItem<string> { Category = "Cool Colors", Item = "Green" });

        CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
        cvs.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));
        cvs.Source = items;

        Binding b = new Binding();
        b.Source = cvs;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
           comboBox1, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);

        myGrid.Children.Add(comboBox1);
    }
}

public class CategoryItem<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - how could I apply it for every ComboBox which I need? Could you show some sample C# code please?

Comment: For every Combobox you should set the `HeaderTemplate` property of its `GroupStyle` through the `StaticResource` binding. I'm going to edit my code...

Comment: Could this be applied through code behind though, or only XAML? As I am trying to do it through code behind. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit and new code. What I'm not understanding though, is how exactly I would go about setting the text for the new GroupStyles?

Comment: Is the code behind part of the link below, clear to you?
http://www.jarloo.com/wpf-combobox-with-groupings/

Comment: That is the link I'm currently using to accomplish this, however I am unsure of how to adopt that method to my requirement, which is adding GroupStyles to comboboxes at run-time. I have managed to add the code which you specified above, however I am unsure of how to adopt this link's explanation to my requirements.

Comment: I read you post once more. As far as I understand 1) you are going to dynamically create some `Combobox`es that have some `CategoryItem`s and 2)apply a specific `GroupStyle` to those. If the main question is how to apply this style to every `Combobox`es you can do it as I explain.

Comment: The part which I haven't understood however, is to set the name of the CategoryItems

Comment: I will try to adopt your code to fit my requirement. Thanks for the help :) +1

Comment: Is it possible to do the above with an ObservableCollection? As that's what I've currently got as the Combobox itemsource

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just one more quick question - Is there anyway that I can display a label instead of string for the item? I've tried changing the type of the CategoryItem class to Label, however the ComboBox is not displaying the label's content, but rather the label object.

Comment: I edited the XAML code. You can assign this new style to comboboxes in the code behind using the same idea as we did for header style

Answer (score 1):

`GroupStyle` property is on combobox, so you need to set it separately and not in template -

```
  <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="GroupStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

**EDIT**

Well, you can't set the `GroupStyle` property from `Style` since it doesn't have any setter associated with it.

You can however add it from code-behind using `Add()` method like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022529/unable-to-set-the-groupstyle-for-a-listbox-via-style) OR you have to create custom `Attached property` explained [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/73ac639f-afdc-4582-805d-9b3bc8a33fe5).

Code behind -

```
        GroupStyle g = new GroupStyle();

        //Create header template
        FrameworkElementFactory control = new
                                  FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        control.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Name");
        DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        dataTemplate.VisualTree = control;

        g.HeaderTemplate = dataTemplate;
        ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
        cmb.GroupStyle.Add(g);
```

Comment: I am unable to do that - it is reporting that GroupStyle is not a DependencyProperty.

Comment: More specifically: `Error 3 The property "GroupStyle" is not a DependencyProperty. To be used in markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type with an accessible instance property "GroupStyle". For attached properties, the declaring type must provide static "GetGroupStyle"  and "SetGroupStyle" methods.`

Comment: Well `GroupStyle` is a DP but it can't be set through `Style` since it doesn't have any setter. However, you can set it through code. Refer to the asnwer here for details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022529/unable-to-set-the-groupstyle-for-a-listbox-via-style

Comment: If I set it from code behind, how can I set the title of the GroupStyle though? Cannot do a simple `groupStyle.Header = "Text"` it seems.

Comment: You have to create `DataTemplate` in code behind. I have edited the answer, have a look.

Comment: Thanks - only thing I'm not understanding is how to set the actual text though? How can I specify what text I would like through the DataTemplate?

Comment: In your XAML you have bind textblock to `Name` property. What is that?